# Can't enable debug context for QOpenGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt5

I want to enable OpenGL logging in my Qt QOpenGLWidget app. Code:

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setMajorVersion(3);
    format.setMinorVersion(2);
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
    format.setOption(QSurfaceFormat::DebugContext);

    app.setApplicationName("MPGLES");
    app.setApplicationVersion("0.0.1");

    MainWidget widget;
    widget.setFormat(format);
    widget.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**mainwidget.cpp**

```
MainWidget::MainWidget(QWidget *parent) : QOpenGLWidget(parent), m_debugLogger(Q_NULLPTR) { }

void MainWidget::initializeGL()
{
    makeCurrent();
    m_functions.initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    m_functions.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

    m_debugLogger = new QOpenGLDebugLogger(context());
    if (m_debugLogger->initialize()) {
        qDebug() << "GL_DEBUG Debug Logger" << m_debugLogger << "\n";
        connect(m_debugLogger, SIGNAL(messageLogged(QOpenGLDebugMessage)), this, SLOT(messageLogged(QOpenGLDebugMessage)));
        m_debugLogger->startLogging();
    }

    initializeMP();
    timer.start(12, this);
}
```

After call

```
m_debugLogger->initialize();
```

I see next output:

```
QOpenGLDebugLogger::initialize(): the current context is not a debug context:
this means that the GL may not generate any debug output at all.
To avoid this warning, try creating the context with the
QSurfaceFormat::DebugContext surface format option.
```

Why i dont can create a QOpenGLDebugLogger? What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Are you sure your hardware/driver supports debug contexts?  I think the `GL_ARB_debug_output` extension is what you're looking for.

Comment: @G.M. I'm not sure, but this code `context()->hasExtension(QByteArrayLit‌​eral("GL_KHR_debug")‌​)` return true.

Comment: @needo did you ever figure this out? I think I'm facing the same problem at the moment

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the QOpenGLContext before using the QOpenGLDebugLogger.

Just like:

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
format.setVersion(3, 3);
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
format.setOption(QSurfaceFormat::DebugContext);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
QOpenGLContext *context = new QOpenGLContext();
context->setFormat(format);
context->create();
```